# Use Regular expression react native on real time

Tags: typescript, react-native, mask

have i started a project on my company using React-Native and TypeScript, and we have a trouble in mask in pt-br... i can't use a default library into npm codes, because isn't flexible code, for now i really want to use a regular expression to convert states and recieve masks, here we using mask phone like this (41) 9 9887-7665 passing a value (41998877665) and return with mask, have i trying so many codes in js but isn't working...

I really just wanna know, how to consume a regular expressions in react-native.

```
  _addMaskPhoneBr(phone: any){  //this is my function to add mask into my screen
    phone = phone.replace(/^[(]?[0-9]{3}[)]?[-\s.]?[0-9]{3}[-/\s.]?[0-9]{4}$/); //mask have i try to apply, i know this will not return a spected result, but after i can use i'll fixit to a mask pt br

    this.setState({ phone: phone }); // set state to reload value into textInput {stateVariable: setValu}
 }
```

Component to user enter a phone...

```
<View style={viewEditStyle}>
 <TextField 
  label={I18n.t("proposalDetail.phone")} 
  value={this.state.phone} //this reload value from state
  keyboardType="numeric"
  onChangeText={value => this._addMaskPhoneBr(value)} // this set function a value to add mask
  maxLength={16}
 />
```

[Pic from Console.log returns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVMgA.png)

Thanks for all help!

Comment: I think the problem with the logic is that you do not supply the case when user backspace in the textinput.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have i fix with this code:

```
  _addMaskPhoneBr(phone: string){  
try {
  phone =  phone.replace(/[^\d]+/g,'');
  this.setState({ phone: phone });
  if(phone.length == 10){
    phone = (phone.length > 1 ? "(" : "")+phone.substring(0, 2) + (phone.length > 2 ? ")" : "")+(phone.length > 2 ? " " : "") + phone.substring(2,6) + (phone.length > 3 ? "-" : "") + phone.substring(6, 10);
  } else {
    phone = (phone.length > 1 ? "(" : "")+phone.substring(0, 2) + (phone.length > 2 ? ")" : "")+(phone.length > 2 ? " " : "") + phone.substring(3,2) + (phone.length > 3 ? " " : "") + phone.substring(3, 7) + (phone.length > 7 ? "-" : "") + phone.substring(7, 12);
  }
} catch(e){
  this.setState({ phone: phone });
}
this.setState({ phone: phone });
```

}